# Cannot successfully create custom cursor from image

Tags: html, css

Here is the hierarchy of my website.

[image]

I am trying to set paw.png as my custom cursor.

Here is my code for the custom cursor in main.css.

```html
#body{
 cursor: url('Images/paw.png'), auto;
}
```

I am not sure why it's not working and only the default cursor appears. It would be great if someone could help me fix this issue.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it `#body`? Because I use just `body`.

Comment: Also make sure the path is correct to the image.

Answer (score 3):

If you intend to apply that cursor to your complete page, you should use the selector `body`, not `#body` (which is an id selector)

```
body{
    cursor: url('Images/paw.png'), auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

make sure the URL is right and that you're selecting the right element, also there are some limitations on the size of the image that you can use as a custom cursor.

In Firefox, for example, the limit is **128×128px** (Firefox 3.6-3.6.6 on Windows limits this to **32x32px**.) so, try to use a 32x32px image to be in the safe zone

for more information: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_User_Interface/Using_URL_values_for_the_cursor_property)

Answer (score 1):

Well assuming that you have an `id="body"` on the `body` tag, you also need to fix the url which should be relative to the .css file and not to the root.

```
#body{
    cursor: url('../Images/paw.png'), auto;
}
```